# Uncaught TypeError: react_native_web_dist_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.DatePickerAndroid is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack, expo

I'm running a react native code using expo, all things work right in expo go on android but when i want to run expo on browser i get this error Uncaught TypeError: react_native_web_dist_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.DatePickerAndroid is undefined.
How to resolve it ?

Here is a screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns2qm.png)

Comment: Which picker are you using?

Comment: @FrancescoClementi datepicker

Comment: which npm package...